# How do I disable WiFi auto reconnect for a particular SSID programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-wifi

How can I disable WiFi auto reconnect for a particular SSID programmatically? We can do it manually as given in the screenshot. I wanted to know how can we do it inside of an app.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at the android api documentation for the WifiManager [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager).

> a) See WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder#build() for new mechanism to trigger connection to a Wi-Fi network. b) See addNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List), [removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List%3Candroid.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSuggestion%3E)) **for new API to add Wi-Fi networks for consideration when auto-connecting to wifi.** Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always return -1.

If you then look at *[removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List) Android-API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List%3Candroid.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSuggestion%3E))*

> Remove some or all of the network suggestions that were previously provided by the app. See WifiNetworkSuggestion for a detailed explanation of the parameters. See WifiNetworkSuggestion#equals(Object) for the equivalence evaluation used.
> Requires Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

So if you've provided a network suggestion with your app, you can also remove this suggestion again. This way, it won't auto reconnect anymore.

**Edit:** Please also consider this:

> If the user uses the Wi-Fi picker to explicitly disconnect from one of
> the network suggestions when connected to it, then that network is
> ignored when it is still in range. During this period, that network
> will not be considered for auto-connection, even if the app removes
> and re-adds the network suggestion corresponding to the network.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
List<WifiConfiguration> lists = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration wc : lists ) {
     if(wc.SSID != null && wc.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
          wifiManager.disconnect();
          wifiManager.enableNetwork(wc.networkId, true);
          wifiManager.reconnect();

          break;
     }           
}
```

Comment: I wanted to disable it not to enable the auto-reconnect. enableNetwork function will not work if the connection is established from WiFi settings

Comment: For me this *may* reconnect to the old SSID.